# How to store incoming files with new names in Python?

Tags: file, python-3.x

I have a **python3** based implementation where an incoming data is checked and the end result is stored in a file with a *fixed name*.

```
with open(fileName.tar, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(dumpIncomingData)
```

the `fileName.tar` is hard-coded as of now for e.g. `incomingFile.tar`. The problem is the file keeps getting over-written everytime a new incoming data is detected and that is not what I want. I want that the files written everytime are written in a different file everytime viz. :

- `incomingData1.tar`
- `incomingData2.tar` ...

How can I execute this idea in a pythonic way?

### Code Snippet

```
 from os import chdir
 PATH = '/tmp/'
 FILENAME = 'incomingData.tar'


 while True:
       Do some processes

       if(condition = True):
            print("file decoded")
            chdir(PATH)
            with open(FILENAME, 'wb') as f:
                 f.write(dumpData)
            break
```

`dumpData` is a function of a module I am using and that shouldn't be of a concern here.

Comment: Do you need the process to be aware of existing files, e.g. if `data1` and `data2` already exist, the process should start with `data3`? What about concurrency issues? Does your processing tool "own" the target directory or are there potentially multiple writers?

Comment: I think if the process should only be aware of the existing file names. like you said if `dataN` exists then write to `dataN+1`. There are no potential multiple writers just one single process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an easier *hack* solution for my query. As opposed to @dhke's solution I used a simple for loop within a function `open_next_file`.

#### Logic

1. when the function is called start a for-loop with whichever range one feels is sufficient.
2. check for the same format files names within the target folder. If the filename does not exist write the data in it and break out of the for loop
3. If the filename exists do nothing since you don't want to overwrite on any received files

### Code

```
 # Function to generate subsequent file with number suffix

 from os import chdir, path

 def open_next_file(template='incomingData{}.txt'):

        for serial in range(10):
            if not path.exists(template.format(serial)):
                 # if filename does not exist create on and write in it

                 with open(template.format(serial), 'w') as f:
                     f.write("hello %s \n" %str(serial)) # write stuff..

                 break # once the file is written break free

            else:
                # if filename found do nothing
                # don't want to overwrite on existing files

                pass

 def main():

       chdir('/tmp/')
       open_next_file()

if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
```

### Test

I will pre-define `incomingDatax.txt` in `/tmp/` using

```
 touch incomingData{0..4}.txt
```

This will create empty files from `incomingData0.txt` to `incomingData4.txt` in the folder.

Upon running the above mentioned code a new file `incomingData5.txt` in the folder.

and upon `cat incomingData5.txt` I get `hello 5` while as the already existing files are unchanged.

#### Note

I am giving the example using `.txt` but `.tar` to the `template` variable and with `wb` as the parameter for `open()` should do the trick too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just count up the sequence number until you hit a free filename?

```
from itertools import count
import os

def open_next_file(template='incomingData{serial}.tar'):
    for filename in (template.format(serial=serial) for serial in count()):
        try:
            return open(filename, 'xb')
        except OSError:
            if not os.path.exists(filename):
                raise
```

This will yield an open file with filename as the next available from the sequence `incomingData0.tar`, `incomingData1.tar`, and so on. The operation is atomic as long as `os.open(..., O_CREAT | O_EXCL)` is atomic (which it usually is).

For Python 2 not support open mode `'x'`, but it is possible to emulate the behavior using `os.open(..., os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL)`. In Python 3 `mode='xb'` is sufficient.

Comment: Looks cool will give it a try and revert back. Plus I am using Python 3 so should `open()` be a problem ?

Comment: @Shan-Desai Python 2 doesn't support `'x'`, but one can emulate it using `os.open()`. I just added the comment for eventuall Python 2 users. For you, the solution should work.

Comment: thanks for the help, figured it out with an easier way!